# Распаковка zip в Phonegap

Tags: phonegap, jquery, javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста хороший плагин PhoneGap для распаковки zip архива.

Answer (score 1):

Обычной `javascript` библиотекой, которая умеет распаковывать этот формат.

Например [zip.js](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/)

Comment: А разрешит ли устройство распаковать ?

Comment: @kostya вам что нужно будет позже сделать с распакованными файлами? Если сохранить на устройство, то сохранять нужно через API phonegap.

Comment: Да, надо распаковать на флешку.

Comment: @kostya так в чем проблема то? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21334174/unzipping-file-in-phonegap-using-zip-js

Comment: А где же здесь принятый ответ ?

Comment: @kostya в самом вопросе ответ.

Comment: )) Ну надеюсь что это так